# Want selected values inserted in the text

Tags: javascript, html

I have these two dropdown menus that generates a picture that pops up depending on selection. But I also want the selected values to be inserted into the text on the same page when the "View your product" button is pressed.

```
function f(){
var gid=function(i){return document.getElementById(i);};
var version_id=gid("two").value;
var arch_id=gid("three").value;
var width = 670;
var height = 800;
var left = (screen.width/2)-(width/2);
var top = (screen.height/2)-(height/2);
if( version_id ==='default' || arch_id === 'default'){return;}

window.open('images/shop/' + version_id + '_' + arch_id + '.jpg', "_blank",
'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no,
scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width='+width+',
height='+height+',top='+top+', left='+left );   
}    




<p class="item_name1">Chose frame</p></br>   
<select name="mycomp1" id="two" style="width:185px;" data-maincss="blue">
<option name="one" value="b1" title="images/black3.jpg"></option>
<option  name="two" value="b2" title="images/silver.jpg"></option>
<option value="b3" title="images/white.jpg"></option>
</select>   


<p class="item_name">Chose fabric</p></br>
<select name="mycomp2" id="three" style="width:185px;" data-maincss="blue">
<option name="one" value="c1" title="images/black.jpg"></option>
<option  name="two" value="c2" title="images/green.jpg"></option>
<option value="c3" title="images/red.jpg"></option>
<option value="c4" title="images/blue.jpg"></option>
</select>

<input  onclick="Javascript:f();" value="View your product" type="button"/>
```

Comment: where do you want the value to be inserted

Comment: In to any text field on the page

Comment: In the new window or in the page with select elements

Comment: Sorry, actually  on both if possible

Comment: It is easy in the current page(with select elements)

Comment: Yes, got that now! Any idea on how to get it on to the next page?

Comment: You are opening a image in the new page... may be you can set it as the title of the page... may not be possible to add it as a content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify this to suit your purposes.

```
function f(){
var gid=function(i){return document.getElementById(i);};
var version_id=gid("two").value;
var arch_id=gid("three").value;
var width = 670;
var height = 800;
var left = (screen.width/2)-(width/2);
var top = (screen.height/2)-(height/2);
if( version_id ==='default' || arch_id === 'default'){return;}

var newWindow = window.open('images/shop/' + version_id + '_' + arch_id + '.jpg',"_blank",
'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no, resizable=no,
 copyhistory=no,width='+width+',height='+height+',top='+top+', left='+left);   
}  
//create scriptedText here before inserting
newWindow.document.getElementByd('textContainer').innerHTML = scriptedText;
```

I hope this helps